# Summations of Lists

Tags: functions, summation

I'm trying to find how many numbers between 1 and 1000, which are not either prime or the sum of successive primes.

I've managed to create the list of all the primes between 1 and 1000:

```
primes = With[{list = Range[1000]}, Pick[list, PrimeQ[list]]]
```

And the sum:

```
sum[k_] := Sum[primes[[n]], {n, 1, k}]
```

which gives the summation of the primes from `Prime[1]` to `Prime[k]`.

How can I adapt this summation to be the sum of successive primes?

i.e. `Prime[1] + Prime[2] , Prime[2] + Prime[3]` etc.?

And how can I use that to create a list of numbers which aren't prime or the sum of successive primes?

Comment: What do you mean by sum of successive primes?

Comment: Once the list of prime numbers is created, I want to create another list where I add the first and second primes, then the second and third primes, third and forth, and so on. i.e 2+3=5, 3+5=8, 5+7=12 etc.

Comment: Have a look at `Partition`.

Comment: Try this: `(#1 + #2) & @@@ Partition[primes, 2, 1]`

Comment: You might like `BlockMap[Total, primes, 2, 1]`

Answer (score 2):

Here are the sums of successive primes, which are all the way upto $1088$

```
primeSums = Table[Prime[i + 1] + Prime[i], {i, 100}];
```

Here are primes upto 1069:

```
primes = Table[Prime[i], {i, 180}];
```

We consider the **Complement** of first 1000 numbers from these lists:

```
Complement[Range[1000], primes, primeSums]
```

which gives what you seek. For example, for the first 100 numbers, we get

```
Complement[Range[100], primes, primeSums]
```

> {1, 4, 6, 9, 10, 14, 15, 16, 20, 21, 22, 25, 26, 27, 28, 32, 33, 34,
>   35, 38, 39, 40, 44, 45, 46, 48, 49, 50, 51, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 62,
>   63, 64, 65, 66, 69, 70, 72, 74, 75, 76, 77, 80, 81, 82, 85, 86, 87,
>   88, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 98, 99}

Answer (score 0):

```
With[{primes = Prime @ Range @ PrimePi @ 1000}, Length @ 
 Complement[Range @ 1000, primes, Total[Partition[primes, 2, 1], {2}]]]
```

> 739